# Use visible width inside scroll container

Tags: html, css, overflow, sticky

I have some sticky divs inside a scroll container. In order to make them properly scroll to the far side of the page I had to give them `display: inline-block`. Unfortunately this doesn't look very well when the user scrolls down and the sticky element overlaps the other content. How can I make the `.sticky` element have 100% of the visible width?

```css
html, body
{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.scroll-container
{
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.outer-container
{
  display: inline-block;
}
.sticky
{
  background: #ffa;
  display: inline-block;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  
}
.inner-container
{
  display: flex;
}
.inner-container > div
{
  background: #aff;
  min-width: 10em;
  min-height: 10em;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll-container">
  <div class="outer-container">
    <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="sticky">Sticky</div>
    <div class="inner-container">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try adding `width: 100vw` to your `.sticky` class. Is that the effect you want?

Comment: That would only work in the given example, unfortunately there's a sidebar (to the left of the scroll-container) of unknown width.